# Solana error creating memo program (Node is unhealthy - solana web3)

Tags: web3.js, memo

Good morning all, i am working on a web app, in wich i need to make some Transaction to memo program, i'm currently pointing to https://api.testnet.solana.com and everytime i run the js script, i recive this error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Node is unhealthy
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6812:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6769:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:6759:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (PROJECT_PATH/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:2219:21)
    at async sendRawTransaction (PROJECT_PATH/dist/src/core/sol.js:49:12)
    at async Object.stampOnSol (PROJECT_PATH/dist/src/core/sol.js:70:16) {
  logs: undefined
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, "node is unhealthy" often means that the node has fallen behind from the rest of the network, so you either need to wait for it to catch up, or you need to use another RPC node.

However, I can tell you that testnet is currently down, so you'll need to use another network until it's back up, either devnet or a local `solana-test-validator`.

Comment: Thank you very much really, i was freaking out about this, now i am calm, i will try with devnet or another test node